# Storage Options for 2^96 Key Value Pairs?

Tags: sql, database, architecture, cloud, nosql

What options would one have for a storage of a database containing 2^96 key value pairs? This is an unthinkable number of values, and I would like to get any sort of ideas on how much storage a database like this would occupy, and if there are any options on the best place to host it.

The total number of key value pairs is: 904625697166532776746648320380374280100293470930272690489102837043110636675

Comment: I'm sort of thinking . . . not in this universe.

Comment: Chuck Norris doesn't do databases, but Gordon Linoff can remember them for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If we use Unicode characters conceptually that could be base 65536, and each one takes 4 bytes to encode so we have to inflate 904625697166532776746648320380374280100293470930272690489102837043110636675 by 4 even though we divide it by 65536. Dividing the result by 1024 sufficient times to get into terabytes leaves us looking at about 5x10<sup>58</sup> terabytes, though that is assuming that all keys are the same length. In practice, the first key would be one character etc so in reality we might be able to get away with a good chunk fewer terabytes to store the keys. I don't what he exact formula would be and it's a bit early in the morning, but it certainly makes it a lot more doable. Woohoo.

Now, how big are your values?